# C++ Program Assigning 0 to txt File's Empty Lines

Tags: c++

I am trying to complete a program that should display a college course summary, and I am having problems to properly display all the student names and scores because my program is assigning the value of 0 to the text file's empty lines. How can I skip to the next line and ignore empty lines... is there any command for that? Here's the part of the code that's giving me problems:

```
while (getline(studentFile, name))
{
    getline(studentFile, str);
    score = atoi(str.c_str());

    if (min > score)
    {
        min = score;
    }
    if (max < score)
    {
        max = score;
    }
    sum += score;
    count++;

    cout << setw(40) << left << name << setw(20) << left << score << endl;
}
```

Comment: `if (!str.empty()) { /* perform your current logic */ }`

Comment: `score < min` is a lot easier for me to parse when your intent is check for a new minimum. Similar reversal for max. I'm also not sure the double getline is desired. You are discarding every other entry are you not?

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the string that `getline()` outputs to see if it is empty or not, eg

```
while (getline(studentFile, name))
{
    if (name.empty()) continue;

    if (!getline(studentFile, str)) {
        // error handling... 
    }
    else if (str.empty()) {
        // no value, do something else...
    }
    else {
        // process value... 
    }
    ... 
}
```